# Unity editor gets stuck on compiling cpp for il2cpp when I want to build my app

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, arm64, build-error, il2cpp

I'm using Unity Editor 2022.3.4f1 and I need to build my application in 64 bits for the requirements of Google Play, but unfortunately when I select IL2CPP in the player settings and then select ARM64, it momentarily completes the build to arm64, then freezes in the build at the "compiling cpp for il2cpp (arm32)" step.

This is the error in the console (I don't know if this error is related, but it appears in the console after the build):

> TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
> UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args,
> UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args,
> UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess
> (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget
> target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath,
> System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32
> width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options ,
> UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry,
> UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

I don't know what to even try

Comment: check things like turn off your av..  if it "freezes" try leaving it all day. Ive had a blank project take > 8 hours due to some config of the machine imposed upon me.

Comment: It helped! I waited 40 minutes, and it just finished. thank you